# Find the integrating factor of $(x^2y-2xy^2)\,dx+(x^3-3x^2y)\,dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

> Find the integrating factor of the differential equation: $$(x^2y-2xy^2)\,dx+(x^3-3x^2y)\,dy=0$$

**What I tried:**

This is a homogeneous equation.

Therefore,

$$I.F=\frac{1}{Mx+Ny}=\frac{1}{(x^2y-2xy^2)x+(x^3-3x^2y)y}=\frac{1}{x^3y-2x^2y^2+x^3y-3x^2y^2}$$

However, the given answer is:

$$I.F=\frac{1}{x^2y^2}$$

Comment: Isn't $$I.F=\frac{1}{Mx-Ny}$$ what theorem you have used?

Comment: @user108128 If $ M$ and $N$ are both homogeneous functions in $x,y$ of same degree and $Mx+Ny \ne 0 $, then $\frac{1}{Mx+Ny}$ is an integrating factor.

Comment: What $M$ , $N$, maybe in $f=\dfrac{M}{N}$

Comment: @user108128 Here $M=(x^2y-2xy^2)$ and $N=(x^3-3x^2y)$

Comment: @Soumee : I suggest to you to write in your question the exact wording of the theorem that you use, without forgetting to fully specify the conditions of validity for its application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you apply the so-called "theorem" on convenient condition, but the equation that you found is false. Just check it with the correct integrating factor :
$$I.F.=x^2y^4$$
$$x^2y^4\left((x^2y-2xy^2)\,dx+(x^3-3x^2y)\,dy\right)=0$$
$$(x^4y^5-2x^3y^6)\,dx+(x^5y^4-3x^4y^5)\,dy=0$$
$$d(\frac15 x^5y^5-\frac12 x^4y^6)=0$$
$$\frac15 x^5y^5-\frac12 x^4y^6=C$$

Comment: Sir, can you please help me with this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2881062/394202

Comment: Hi Soumee!  Meanwhile you got an answer from Nosrati. I think that is sufficient to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Making the Substitution $$y(x)=xv(x)$$ then we get

$$\frac{dv(x)}{dx}=\frac{-5v(x)^2+2v(x)}{x(3v(x)-1)}$$ and this is
$$\frac{\frac{dv(x)}{dx}(3v(x)-1)}{-5v(x)^2+2v(x)}=\frac{1}{x}$$
and we can integrate

$$\int \frac{\frac{dv(x)}{dx}(3v(x)-1)}{-5v(x)^2+2v(x)}dx=\int \frac{1}{x}dx$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Sir, what is wrong with my approach?

Comment: Sir, can you please help me with this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2881062/394202

Answer (score 1):

However I'm not familiar with your method, but perhaps this This method for homogeneous equation may help. We have
$$f(x,y)=-\dfrac{x^2y-2xy^2}{x^3-3x^2y}=y'$$
is homogeneous in sense of
$$\color{red}{f(tx,ty)=t^\alpha f(x,y)}$$
then 
$$y'=-\dfrac{\frac{y}{x}-2(\frac{y}{x})^2}{1-3\frac{y}{x}}$$
with $u=\dfrac{y}{x}$
$$u'x+u=-\dfrac{u-2u^2}{1-3u}$$
which is separable.