# Convert $(1+2x)^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-6(1+2x)\frac{dy}{dx}+16y=8(1+2x)^2$ to a form with constant coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Convert the differential equation** $$(1+2x)^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-6(1+2x)\frac{dy}{dx}+16y=8(1+2x)^2$$ **to a form with constant coefficient.**

> How do we arrive at the following?

Let $1+2x=e^z$

$\therefore z=\log (2x+1)$

> So that $(2x+1)\frac{dy}{dx}=2\frac{dy}{dz}=2D'y$
>
> and $(2x+1)^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=2^2.D'(D'-1)y$

Answer (score 1):

This is Euler equation
$$(1+2x)^2y''-6(1+2x)y'+16y=8(1+2x)^2$$
with substitution $1+2x=e^z$ or $z=\ln(1+2x)$ where $1+2x>0$ we have
$$
2\dfrac{dy}{dz}=2\dfrac{dy}{dx}\dfrac{dx}{dz}=2y'\dfrac{e^z}{2}=(1+2x)y'
$$
and
$$
2.2\dfrac{d^2y}{dz^2}=2\dfrac{d}{dz}(2\dfrac{dy}{dz})=2\dfrac{d}{dx}((1+2x)y')\dfrac{dx}{dz}=2\left(2y'+(1+2x)y''\right)\dfrac{e^z}{2}=2(1+2x)y'+(1+2x)^2y''$$
or
$$(1+2x)y'=2\dfrac{dy}{dz}~~~~,~~~~(1+2x)^2y''=4\dfrac{d^2y}{dz^2}-4\dfrac{dy}{dz}$$
then we have a new equation respect to $z$ variable:
$$y''-4y'+4y=2e^{2z}$$

Comment: The LHS is okay but my RHS is $2e^{2z}$. Are you sure with your RHS?

Comment: You are right. RHS is $2e^{2z}$, thanks.

Comment: Please then write it in your answer!?

Comment: Do you like it?

Comment: Yes, now it's very welcome

Comment: According to some doctors, writing is the best form of exercise.

Comment: I agree with you